regex with array
I want to check whether the plates are in the correct format with regex, but this is with the code I wrote, all my plates are orange, so the function returns false anyway. How i can fix it?
static bool PlakaFormat(string plaka)
{
    string[] formatlar =
    {
        @"^\d{2}\s[A-Z]\s\d{4}$",
        @"^\d{2}\s[A-Z]\s\d{5}$",
        @"^\d{2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s\d{3}$",
        @"^\d{2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s\d{4}$",
        @"^\d{2}\s[A-Z]{3}\s\d{2}$",
        @"^\d{2}\s[A-Z]{3}\s\d{3}$"
    };

    foreach (var format in formatlar)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(plaka, format))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}


private void btn_kontrol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        string plaka = rows.Cells[0].Value?.ToString();
  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(plaka))
        {
            
            if (!PlakaFormat(plaka))
            {
                rows.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            }
            else
            {
                
            }

        }
        else
        {
            rows.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        }
    }
}

I tried to write and perform this operation in the button rather than in the function, but I still failed.

Can you give examples of what's in plaka?

it's like "34ASD123"

"34ASD123" doesn't have whitespace, though ... if had, it would work out: https://regex101.com/r/tW9tYH/1 or you need to make the \s optional?

You maybe want \s* instead of \s to find any number (including none) of whitespaces?

Did you debug the issue and see where it goes whrong? Shouldn't be a big problem to loop through 5 regexes and see which one should match while it doesn't.

Another thought: Do you only need to validate the format or are you going on to further dissect the plates for (I dunno) area codes or something? In that case, it would probably be easier to try-parse them and treat "fail-to-parse" as 'invalid'.

\s seems to be the issue since in the comments you provided plaka "34ASD123"
Please see this RegexCheatSheet
Change your regex to this:
string[] formatlar =
{
    @"^\d{2}[A-Z]\d{4}$",       // Matches "34A1234"
    @"^\d{2}[A-Z]\d{5}$",       // Matches "34A12345"
    @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$",    // Matches "34AS123"
    @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$",    // Matches "34AS1234"
    @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}$",    // Matches "34ASD12"
    @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$"     // Matches "34ASD123"
};

So that your plates does not require whitespace characters..
Here is updated the code you have provided so that you can see which plates are working and which are not:
static bool PlakaFormat(string plaka)
{
    string[] formatlar =
    {
        @"^\d{2}[A-Z]\d{4}$",
        @"^\d{2}[A-Z]\d{5}$",
        @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$",
        @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$",
        @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}$",
        @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$"
    };

    foreach (var format in formatlar)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(plaka, format))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void btn_kontrol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        string plaka = row.Cells[0].Value?.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(plaka))
        {
            if (PlakaFormat(plaka))
            {
                // If the format is correctdefault
                row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }
            else
            {
                // If the format is incorrect
                row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Reset to default if no plate is provided
            row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        }
    }
}

Alternatively if whitespaces are considered to be a part of plate use this regex instead:
string[] formatlar =
{
    @"^\d{2}\s*[A-Z]\s*\d{4}$",    // Matches "34A1234" and "34 A 1234"
    @"^\d{2}\s*[A-Z]\s*\d{5}$",    // Matches "34A12345" and "34 A 12345"
    @"^\d{2}\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*\d{3}$", // Matches "34AS123" and "34 AS 123"
    @"^\d{2}\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*\d{4}$", // Matches "34AS1234" and "34 AS 1234"
    @"^\d{2}\s*[A-Z]{3}\s*\d{2}$", // Matches "34ASD12" and "34 ASD 12"
    @"^\d{2}\s*[A-Z]{3}\s*\d{3}$"  // Matches "34ASD123" and "34 ASD 123"
};

This regex uses \s* the * says that zero or more whitespaces are pleasible
